# Imagem resolution responsive

Tags: images, html, thumbnails

I have a `add_image_size` to resize an image, but when i have 980px of resolution, the image still the same size. I would like the image be 100% when the resolution is lower than 980px, but I need to continue using the code `add_thumbnail_size`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the timthumb for resize your images as you want.

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    // get the src of the large size featured image
                    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large' );
                    $thumbnailSrc = $src[0];
                    // output image resized with timthumb 
                    ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($postid, 'post_link', true) ?>" target="_blank">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $thumbnailSrc; ?>&h=240&w=245" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <?php } ?>
```

And download that file [timthumb](https://code.google.com/p/timthumb/)

Hopefully your problem solve.

Comment: I dont understood. what should i do?